# Magento products pictures are not sercure, any solution?

Tags: magento-1.7, security

We don't want competitors to be able to download high resolution images from Magento. The front-end URL is:

leatherjacketgear.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/70x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/r/armani-quilted-leather_2.jpg

But you can remove this part of the URL

/cache/1/thumbnail/70x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95

and find the original image here:

leatherjacketgear.com/media/catalog/product/a/r/armani-quilted-leather_2.jpg

:( The original image is returned.

This is not okay with our customer for whom we've done website designing in Magento. They want to protect their images because some companies with in-house developers steals images.

Comment: My suggestion would be to update htaccess so that no images in /media/catalog/* can be access unless "cache" is also in the path. However, this may negatively affect your ability to view the images in the Admin. If it's really a concern, you'll need to just upload the smaller resolution images that you plan on using on the front-end, and not full resolution copies.

Comment: You should add this as an answer here @TylerV.

Answer (score 1):

If you show high resolution images anywhere in the frontend (like with image zoom), it will be possible to crawl them, no matter how hard you try it to make.

If you don't need the high resolution images, the simplest solution is to upload low resolution images.